# Using XMLQUERY to retrieve specific XML data

Tags: xml, db2

I have XML data in the following format held in a specific column as a CLOB.

```
<S>
    <F>
        <Alias>Item1</Alias>
        <Type>String</Type>
        <Value>TestItem</Value>
    </F>
    <F>
        <Alias>Item2></Alias>
        <Type>Integer</Type>
        <Value>53</Value>
    </F>
</S>
```

How can i do the following: Retrieve Value where Alias = 'Item2'.

I've tried

`xmlquery('$STUFF/S/F/A/*' PASSING XMLPARSE(document XMLCOLUMN AS "STUFF")`

thinking it would just show me all the A's.  But doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Show the full query and the intended result

Comment: I'm trying to build the query, so i don't have one.  The above is what i'm trying to get.  I need to build a XMLQUERY statement which extracts the <Value>  from an <F> where the <Alias> is 'Item2'.  I'm trying different combinations of XMLQUERY, XMLPARSE etc

Comment: "I've tried" seems like you ran a query. What is the desired format of the result? Every "item2" in a separate row, all per doc together as a single value, ...?

Comment: Sorry data_henrik,  I thought my initial question contained all the information needed.  Not much more i could add to it.  Anyway, mustaccio has answered my question perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn [XPath expressions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrpathexp.html) if you want to use `XMLQUERY`. For your requirement:

> extracts the <Value> from an <F> where the <Alias> is 'Item2'

the correct expression would be `'$STUFF/S/F/Value[../Alias/text() = "Item2"]/text()`

Comment: Thanks very much mustaccio.  This worked perfectly.  It was that exact expression i was getting stuck at.   Cheers